# Cannot access my applet on browser because of a security exception

Tags: java, mysql, security, applet

I've been working on a Java applet connecting to a MySQL database. I've put the URL on my whitelist, I've signed my applet and it connects well and runs fine in the appletviewer. In my Internet Explorer the applet doesn't work and I get the following message:

```
java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:3306" "connect,resolve")
```

### STACKTRACE:

```
java.net.SocketException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:3306" "connect,resolve")
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.unwrapExceptionToProperClassAndThrowIt(StandardSocketFactory.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at TableFromMySqlDatabase.<init>(TableFromMySqlDatabase.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.

Comment: Are the applet and DB hosted on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to **/etc/tomcat6/policy.d/webapps.policy** file:

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "127.0.0.1:3306", "connect,resolve"; 
permission java.util.PropertyPermission "file.encoding", "read";
```

Also comment out in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

This will help i guess.